# Flume: Data transferring to Server

Tags: hadoop, cloud, cloudera, flume

I am new to Flume-ng. I have to write a program, which can transfer a text file to other program (agent). I know we must know about agent i.e. host-ip, port number etc. Then a source, sink and  a channel should be defined. I just want to transfer a log file to server. My client code is as follows.
public class MyRpcClientFacade {

```
public class MyClient{

  private RpcClient client;
  private String hostname;
  private int port;

  public void init(String hostname, int port) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.port = port;
        this.client = RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(hostname, port);

      }

      public void sendDataToFlume(String data) {
        Event event = EventBuilder.withBody(data, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        try {
          client.append(event);
        } catch (EventDeliveryException e) {
          client.close();
          client = null;
          client = RpcClientFactory.getDefaultInstance(hostname, port);
        }
      }

      public void cleanUp() {
        client.close();
      }
}
```

Above code can send only `String` data to specified process. But i have to send files. Moreover tell me please that whether `Source,Channel and Sink` have to be written onto server? And if so, how to configure and write these three. Please help me. Give a small sample of `Source,Sink And Channel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you just have to get flume client on each node. Then you provide a config file providing information about their behaviors.
For instance, if your node read a file (read each new lines and send them as events to channel ), and send file contents trough a RPC socket. Your configuration will look like :

```
  # sources/sinks/channels list
  <Agent>.sources = <Name Source1>
  <Agent>.sinks = <Name Sink1>
  <Agent>.channels = <Name Channel1> 
  # Channel attribution to a source
  <Agent>.sources.<Name Source1>.channels = <Name Channel1>
  # Channel attribution to sink
  <Agent>.sinks.<Name Sink1>.channels = <Name Channel1>
  # Configuration (sources,channels and sinks)
  # Source properties : <Name Source1>
  <Agent>.sources.<Name Source1>.type = exec
  <Agent>.sources.<Name Source1>.command = tail -F test
  <Agent>.sources.<Name Source1>.channels = <Name Channel1>
  # Channel properties : <Name Channel1>
  <Agent>.channels.<Name Channel1>.type = memory
  <Agent>.channels.<Name Channel1>.capacity = 1000
  <Agent>.channels.<Name Channel1>.transactionCapacity = 1000
  # Sink properties : <Name Sink1>
  <Agent>.sinks.<Nom Sink1>.type = avro
  <Agent>.sinks.<Nom Sink1>.channel = <Nom Channel1>
  <Agent>.sinks.<Nom Sink1>.hostname = <HOST NAME or IP>
  <Agent>.sinks.<Nom Sink1>.port = <PORT NUMBER>
```

Then you will have to set an agent, which will read on an avro source on same port and process the event the way you want to store them.
I hope it helps ;)